# Time spent in cpu frequency on core i5

Tags: cpufreq, intel-cpu

On my old server with AMD Athlon X2 5050e processor, I have /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state that tells me how much time the processor spent in each frequency state.
Now I have a machine with an Intel i5-4690 that does not have such a stats directory.
I would like to see how much time the processor spends at what frequency. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but complicated and would also require some post processing. From the kernel source tree, using the `tools/power/x86/intel_pstate_tracer/intel_pstate_tracer.py` python script could acquire and extract a trace sample over the desired time. Extracted data would include frequencies and pstates for each CPU.

Comment: By default your i5-4690 processor will use the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. You can go back to the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver by adding `intel_pstate=disable` to your grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. After `update-grub` and a reboot your stats directory and information would be present again. Suggest you keep an original copy of `/etc/default/grub` before editing it.

Comment: Thanks, the first option would need a little much processing, with the second I can keep doing things the way I did.